# Rebuild child widget from scratch including state in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I want to rebuild completely a child widget, including its state (causing the state to be deleted and then created from scratch, such that specifically initState will be called). How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you tell why you want to do that, it is uncommon,there may be another way

Comment: Please share your code and scenario of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @LoVe it's related to certain behavior of a plugin that I use, which I initialize in initState. It's a bit long to describe. I believe there is a way to solve my issue without what I've asked for, but it'll be a lot more cumbersome, in my opinion, than simply performing a total rebuild, including the state

Comment: Maybe you can move your code in initState directly to the buildMethod, bevore the return. Then the code will be executed also on rebuild

Comment: Ok the only thing I can suggest as I don't think you can achieve what you want in the way you want and as I don't know the details, is that you create a method to reset the state and start a timer from initState which checks each time if it should call the reset method to reset all fields and call setState, or not